# Short URL with bitly_api in python

Tags: python, url

I am trying to shorten url with bitly in python.
This is my code so far:

```
import SETTINGS
import bitly_api

b = bitly_api.Connection(access_token=SETTINGS.API_KEY)
response = b.shorten(uri=full_url)

print response

return response['url']
```

Error that I get is:

```
 File "/Users/Mac/Dropbox/01_MACBOOK/01_Development/02_PYTHON/03_EmailFromPage/bitly.py", line 11, in get_bitly_url
    response = b.shorten(uri=full_url)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bitly_api/bitly_api.py", line 87, in shorten
    data = self._call(self.host, 'v3/shorten', params, self.secret)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bitly_api/bitly_api.py", line 789, in _call
    data.get('status_txt', 'UNKNOWN_ERROR'))
bitly_api.bitly_api.BitlyError: INVALID_ARG_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you might be the type to learn from 'doing', so, here is an awesome course on utilizing the bitly's API, with Python, from CodeAcademy.

http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/bitly

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful, https://medium.com/swlh/a-case-for-shortening-your-aws-pre-signed-urls-fc638dc1b47e article walks you through how to use bit.ly API v4. The official python bit.ly https://github.com/bitly/bitly-api-python doesn't seem supported, nor do they seem to respond in their google support forum.

```
client = BitlyBasicAuthClient()
response = client.shorten_url(yourUrlHere, yourGroupIdHere)
shortened_url = json.dumps(response, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
print(shortened_url)
```